# php symfony cc in backend?

Tags: php, apache, symfony1

is possible make 
**php symfony cc**

in backend.php on my page? if yes, how? i would like clear cache in my backend on page, not going to server

Comment: This question is really vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always call the system() function:

```
system("php symfony cc");
```

But I'm sure there's a better way...
Actually, you must be able to call the function which clears cache inside your code, it's in the class sfCacheClearTask: https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/1.4/lib/task/cache/sfCacheClearTask.class.php

I think this should work:

```
$command = new sfCommandApplicationTask();
$command->runTask('cache:clear');
```

Comment: Make sure the permissions of all the files or directories are correct. If you have symfony generated files or directories owned by root, this will cause problems.